# Refresh State in Action Bar Sherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

i want to rotate refresh in actionbarsherlock.previously i was using actionbar and was doing setRefreshActionItemState.

Answer (score 0):

For refresh state you may try this link to get the answer [Refresh menu item animation in ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539359/refresh-menu-item-animation-in-actionbarsherlock)..

```
case R.id.refreshMenuItem:
    isRefreshing = true;
    item.setActionView(R.layout.action_bar_indeterminate_progress);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) item.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.loadingImageView);
    ((AnimationDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the link..But i need to set back the refresh state some whereelse like after loading something i need to set it back to original state ..That doesn't happen in your link righjt