# android:animateLayoutChanges="true" not working with toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I'm trying to set visibility of some elements and  I'm using the android:animateLayoutChanges="true" to animate this changes, the animation of the Floating Action Button happens ok, but not works with the menu items, they just blink. Here it is my xml and code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="@dimen/standard_elevation"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/rlMainInside"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_create_black_48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/main_center_image"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>



    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="320dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I use this method to set the visibility of some elements:

```
private void setMenuVisibility(boolean drawerOpenned) {
    Menu menu = myToolbar.getMenu();

    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++){
        menu.getItem(i).setVisible(!drawerOpenned);

    }

    fab.setVisibility(drawerOpenned ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Can someone help me? I tried to put android:animateLayoutChanges="true" inside the toolbar element, but not happened also.

Comment: You might need to recall the option menu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539359/refresh-menu-item-animation-in-actionbarsherlock

Comment: I tried, but I think this is not my case. Not worked.